# SharePoint 2007 : Target Audience Unable to Find AD Users

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, web-parts, target-audience

I'm working in SharePoint 2007 web part's target audience, there is a problem to add the AD Groups as target audience, because I not able to find the AD Groups under "Distribution/Security Groups".

The connection between SharePoint and AD has been configured, because the AD Groups or AD users able to find and add in SharePoint (People and Groups), just it cannot be find in web part's target audience.

**Update:**

I would like to add on the user profile has been full crawled, all users in the AD Group has been imported. and yet the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't appear in the audience section, this is due to the SSP not connecting to AD. Check your AD connection string and import logs. Make sure it is importing all the AD users and groups from AD. These are used for audiencing in the SSP (different from the people picker for permissions).

Comment: AD connection should be ok, because I manage to find those AD group in "People and Groups". And the users import via Central Administrator, the log was unable to find the group I want to associate in target audience, could this be the root cause? no warning or error has been found in the users import log

Comment: I had double check the imported users from the logs, the users(from a certain AD Group) was there. and yet still unable to find the AD Group in target audience